# How to change response format of App Services in ASP.NET Boilerplate (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I want to change app service's  response content-type from `application/json` to `application/xml`. One solution I come across is [this](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=27254) but it didn't explain how to configure ABP and use Xml Formatter. Can anyone please explain how to configure ABP for this package i.e `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml`. Simply installing this package and configuring `startup.cs` file with `services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` didn't work. I think ApplicationCoreModule has to be configured. Btw My app service is returning a list of objects.

Here are the images of Results when I execute API in Swagger:

[Request Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE5QH.jpg)

[Response Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sutO1.jpg)

Comment: What you have done is added support for responding in XML; so I'm guessing that you're app now supports both XML and JSON. And the request would have to specify that it wants a response in XML with an Accept header. Is the app currently responding in JSON?

Comment: my request string specify Accept header for XML response: `curl -X POST "http://localhost:21021/api/services/app/Sitemap/GenerateSiteMap" -H "accept: application/xml" -H "Authorization: null"` but app returns JSON objects.

Comment: I've not been able to get this working from an `AppService` either, but if I use a MVC `controller` the response type will be honoured.